# Show deduced type for stream pipeline in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

IntelliJ idea 2016

Is there a way to figure out what generic type is deduced in intellij? I working with kind of larger stream pipeline and sometimes I came across with such misleading error message like `This method cannot be used in a static context` when using a grouping collector like this:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends Number>{
    String str();
}

public final class MyInterfaceUtils{
    public static <T extends Number> Collection<MyInterface<T>> myInterfaces(MyInterface<T> mi){
        //impl goes here
    }
}
```

Now the pipeline itself:

```
Collection<MyInterface<Integer>> col;
//...
Map<String, Collection<MyInterface<Integer>>> m = col.stream()
      .flatMap(mi -> MyInterfaceUtils.muInterfaces(mi).stream())
      .collect(groupingBy(MyInterface::str)); //prints error:
                //Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

But when I replace the declartion with `Map<String, List<MyInterface<Integer>>> m`it works fine. I understand that generic types are not inherited in this way, but the error message was kind of misleading so I had to spent some time figuring out what's going on.

Maybe there's a way to cope with such error messages in intellij?

Comment: I don’t know whether this works in IntelliJ, but in all other IDEs, I simply remove `m`’s declared type, causing a compiler error, and tell the IDE to create that variable, which ends in `m` being created with the inferred type. But I know your problem; it goes deeper than that. Even a misplaced comma or brace can cause the weirdest Generics error messages instead of naming the trivial cause. Atm this applies to all compilers/IDEs with no solution in sight.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is misguiding. What here is wrong is that grouping will return `Map<String, List<...` but not `Map<String, Collection<...` so changing `Collection` to `List` solves compilation problem.

Regarding how to know type of stream pipeline operation. Usually I put cursor on stream pipeline function and [extract variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/extract-variable.html) that gives me variable with type.